# Which question is right?

Tags: adjectives, auxiliary-verbs, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I am confused on how to frame a question.

> Is the patient aware of the procedure?

or

> Does the patient aware of the procedure?

Answer (score 3):

"aware" is an adjective.

It's always useful to try to trace back to your original sentence, because questions are like normal sentences with gaps to fill in.

> I am aware of the procedure.
>   The patient is aware of the procedure.

but

> *The patient does aware of the procedure.
>    <sub>* marks the utterance as ungrammatical</sub>

When forming a question, you swap the subject (*[T]he patient*) and the auxiliary (*is*).

> Is the patient aware of the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct. "Aware" is an adjective, so we ask if the patient *is* aware.